# MySQL Query - replace or remove 0 (zero) in a column, but not remove the digit zero in a word or number?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where one column has 0 for a value.  The problem is that my page that fetches this data show's the 0.

I'd like to remove the 0 value, but only if it's a single 0.  And not remove the 0 if it's in a word or a numeric number like 10, 1990, 2006, and etc.

I'd like to see if you guys can offer a SQL Query that would do that?

I was thinking of using the following query, but I think it will remove any 0 within a word or numeric data.

```
update phpbb_tree set member_born = replace(member_born, '0', '')
```

Hopefully you guys can suggest another method?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: `.. WHERE column_name = 0`? (maybe `= '0'`, I don't really know if you'll need the quotes). And you don't even need to use `replace` if the row only has `0`, you can do use `UPDATE table_name SET column_name = '' WHERE column_name = 0`.

Comment: make a backup first. update table set column='your desire data' where column='0'

Comment: The suggestion by @FirstOne looks right, but maybe you could show us a few records and how you want them to be replaced.

Comment: what's the column type?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi the issue is that I have several different columns in one table that has this issue. Some columns will only hold numbers (year dates YYYY) while other will contain alphanumeric words.

Comment: with what data you will replace the 0 values?

Comment: @FirstOne I don't wish to rename the columns, only the data inside each column.  for example in the table "phpbb_tree" in the column of "born_year" or "street_address" some data is shown as 0 and that shows up in my php page.  I want them blank, instead of a zero showing.

Comment: @Jay-Jay then you better study sql. That's some serious learning gap. The code I proposed will **not** rename the column. It will replace the value!! It's something so easy to test!!!

Comment: @RafaelShkembi, I want them empty.  If the data only has a 0 and nothing else, I want them empty.

Comment: @FirstOne maybe I'm not explaning myself correctly.  A Table has several columns.  Each column has some data for each row I create.  Right? I don't wish to replace or rename the column, only the data value.

Comment: @Jay-Jay you seriously need to study SQL. Take a look at this: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cbaae/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cbaae/1). Run that, then uncomment the update (remove the `#`) and run the select again. You'll see that from bottom-up, the first and the third are empty - they are the values that were 0.

Comment: @RafaelShkembi so you are suggesting this: `update phpbb_tree set member_born='' where member_born='0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussed at the comments you have said that you want to not show 0 values when you fetching the data. The solution is simple and should be like this.

lets supposed that you have make your query and fetch the data with a `$row` variable.

```
if($row['born_year'] == '0'){
    $born_year = "";
} else {
    $born_year = $row['born_year'];
}
```

Another solution is by filtering the query from the begging

```
select * from table where born_year !='0';
```

> update

if you want to remove all the 0 values from your tables you can do it in this way. Consider making a backup before.

```
update table set column='' where column='0';
```

if the value is int change column='0' to column=0